# Implementing a 'once' function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, closures

I have this spec from Jasmine.js which tests a `once` function.  I'm not sure how to implement such a function though.

```
/* Functions that decorate other functions.  These functions return a version of the function
   with some changed behavior. */

// Given a function, return a new function will only run once, no matter how many times it's called
describe("once", function() {
  it("should only increment num one time", function() {
    var num = 0;
    var increment = once(function() {
      num++;
    });
    increment();
    increment();

    expect(num).toEqual(1);
  });
});
```

I don't quite understand what should I do here.  I know I should make a function once(myFunction) {} but other than that, I am stuck.  I figure out this has something to do with closures, still can't my head around it.

Comment: you didnt describe what the problem is.  what do you expect to happen?  what is actually happening?

Comment: Hi Robert, I have to write a function that will pass this spec.  I don't understand on how to fulfill the requirement of this test.

Comment: ok i fixed your question and gave an answer

Comment: You are expected to build a function that has no effect on the ```num``` variable except for the first time it's called. This means, the first time it increments num from 0 to 1. The second time it would yield 2, but since it happens only once, num should still be 1 forever.

Comment: Thanks, yes I am clear on that now.  I just need to know how do I build a function that has no effect on the num variable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Copied from the UnderscoreJS source:

```
  _.once = function(func) {
    var ran = false, memo;
    return function() {
      if (ran) return memo;
      ran = true;
      memo = func.apply(this, arguments);
      func = null;
      return memo;
    };
  };
```

http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html

Comment: Hi Robert,I am not sure if I understand your answer here.  What does exactly that this code do?

Comment: It defines a 'once' function that passes your spec

Comment: @RobertLevy : It looks awesome. But can you explain its functionality as well ?

Answer (score 11):

If you prefer not to use UnderscoreJS, you can implement a simpler "once" function yourself like this:

```
var once = function (func) {
  var result;

  return function () {
    if (func) {
      result = func.apply(this, arguments);
      func = null;
    }

    return result;
  }
};
```

When you pass your function as the argument to this once function (as the parameter as 'func'), it returns a function that can only be called once.

It accomplishes this feat, in short, by creating a results variable and assigning that variable the results of calling your function with its supplied arguments--but **only the first time it is run**. Otherwise, when the function is invoked subsequent times, it will never enter your if statement (because the func variable was set to null in the first invocation) and the value referenced by the results variable (set during the first invocation and accessed via closure) will be returned.

Answer (score 4):

Very, very minimal

```
const once = fn => (...args) => {
  if (!fn) return;
  fn(...args);
  fn = null;
};
```

(Old school version)

```
function once(fn) {
  return function() {
    if (!fn) return;
    fn.apply(null, arguments);
    fn = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate you said it was minimal, but I should note that it doesn't apply arguments nor return values (if a future searcher requires these).

Comment: Args support is trivial. I've edited examples. Thanks to @Alex for original idea.