# Run function only once - functional programming JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a code below,

```
var a = 0;
var addByOne = doOnce(function() { a += 1; });

// I need to define a doOnce function here


// Run addByOne two times
addByOne();
addByOne();
```

This will result the variable a holds 2 as its value.  My question is, how do I make the doOnce function so that it will result in running the function inside doOnce (in the case above, function () { a += 1; } ) just one time.  So no matter how many times addByOne is called, variable a will be incremented just once.

Thanks

Comment: This could be of help to you - http://underscorejs.org/#once

Comment: Do you mean once, full stop, or *once per function passed*?

Comment: You asked this question yesterday.

Comment: I mean once for all full stop.  So no matter how many times addByOne is called, it will not make the variable a incremented again because it has been incremented one time

Comment: I think this is yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836249/implementing-a-once-function-in-javascript

Comment: Yeah it turned out that I still can't figure it out.  I saw the underscore js, but I am looking if there is any other way to do it without the way they do it?

Comment: Here's a good rule to follow for learning javascript: don't use a library or framework to do something if you don't know how to do it in plain javascript. Libraries are there to make your life easier, not to help you get by without knowing the solutions for basic problems.

Comment: Thanks Meredith.  Yes this is what I am trying to do.

Comment: Too bad this was marked as duplicate. Maybe some one can undo that because the other question is not the same. Also the answer is not that great on the other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function doOnce(fn) {
  // Keep track of whether the function has already been called
  var hasBeenCalled = false;
  // Returns a new function
  return function() {
    // If it has already been called, no need to call it again
    // Return (undefined)
    if (hasBeenCalled) return;
    // Set hasBeenCalled to true
    hasBeenCalled = true;
    return fn.apply(this, arguments);
  }
}
```

If you want, you can keep track of the return value and return that instead of undefined.

Comment: This is much more readable than in the underscore js.  Thank you so much.

Comment: can you explain more about this as the argument of apply? I understand the concept of call and apply in doing OOP js, but not so much in functional programming.  What and how does 'this' works here?

Comment: @user122652 Basically, if you call the function in the context of something else e.g. `addByOne.call(something)` it will pass the context on.
`var a = {};
function b() { this.c = 5; }
b.apply(a);` Here `a.c` will be 5.

Comment: But in fn.apply, this refers to which context?

Comment: Whatever it was called with (most likely window or undefined). But, as I said, if you called `addByOne.call(something)` it would pass the context on. (In this case, it wouldn't do anything because `addByOne` doesn't reference `this` anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved by creating a `doOnce` function which returns a wrapper for calling the passed function if it has not already been run. This may look something like this;

```
doOnce = function(fn) {
    var hasRun = false,
        result;
    return function() {
        if (hasRun === false) {
            result = fn.apply(this, arguments);
            hasRun = true;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```